# Is there any way to recognise or extract underlined words using python from image?

Tags: python, ocr

I have a bunch of words extracted from a particular image using  Tesseract OCR library. After doing so, is there any way to detect words which are being underlined or they have a box around them?

Comment: What OCR library are you using? Please include this detail in your question

Comment: what have you tried so far?  which library are you using and what is not working?

Comment: I have used tesseract library and I get the words presented in the image. Is there any custom way to extract only underlined texts or words? Any relative insights are appreciated.